Question on Hebrew phrase in Job- can לֹא negate יֵשׁ and if not, what does לֹא יֵשׁ mean
In the WLC, Job 9:33 reads לֹא יֵשׁ־בֵּינֵינוּ מוֹכִיחַ יָשֵׁת יָדוֹ עַל־שְׁנֵינוּ
My translation translates "לֹא יֵשׁ" as "there is no". I have heard that לֹא can't negate יֵשׁ; you have to use אַיִן to say "there is no". So my question is, what does this phrase mean? Is לֹא negating יֵשׁ here in spite of normal rules? Is that actually a rule that only applies to modern Hebrew? Or does this mean "Oh that there were" (I believe that's what it would mean if it was לֻא), and if so, why does it have a holem instead of a qibbuts?

Hey Ish-bosheth! Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! We are glad you are here. When you get a chance, please take the  tour to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. Also consider going through the Help Center's  sections on asking and answering questions.

The Grammar, GKC writes concerning this verse:

[§ 152d]      2. The negation of noun-clauses by לֹא (as opposed to the
regular negation by אֵין) always includes a certain emphasis, since
the force of the negation falls rather upon a particular word (cf.
e.g. Ez 36:32), than upon the whole clause. In 2 S 3:34 יָדֶ֫יךָ
לֹֽא־אֲסוּרוֹת thy hands were not bound, a participle is thus
specially negatived by לֹא; cf. Ps 74:9, where, however, לֹא is
separated from the participle by אִתָּ֫נוּ, and Jb 12:3. As a rule,
noun-clauses with a pronominal subject are thus negatived by לֹא, Gn
20:12, Nu 35:23 (Dt 4:42, 19:4); 1 S 15:29, 2 S 21:2, Jer 4:22, Ps
22:7, Jb 28:14, parallel with אֵין; generally with לֹא before a
substantival predicate, e. g. Ex 4:10 לֹא אִישׁ דְּבָרִים אָנֹ֫כִי I
am not a man of words; Am 5:18.—Noun-clauses with a substantival
subject, Gn 29:7, Nu 23:19, Is 22:2, 44:19, Hag 1:2, Ps 22:3, Jb 9:32,
18:17, 21:9, 22:16, 36:26 (with וְ of the apodosis); 41:2; in Jb 9:33
even לֹא יֵשׁ non est is used instead of אֵין.—In Pr 18:5 לֹא is used
before an adjectival predicate; in 1 S 20:26 (where a preceding
noun-clause is negatived by בִּלְתִּי) read לֹא טֹהָר with the LXX,
for לֹא טָהוֹר. On לֹא for אֵין in circumstantial clauses to express
attributive ideas, see u below.
(Wilhelm Gesenius, Gesenius’ Hebrew Grammar, eds. E. Kautzsch and A.
E. Cowley, 2d, Accordance electronic ed. (Oxford: Clarendon Press,
1910), paragraph 10.)

So לֹא can be used to negate יֵשׁ. But, you're right, that we would expect אֵין. Gesenius concludes that this is done for emphasis.
Also, BDB notes that this could be an aramism:

(h) לֹא יֵשׁ † Jb 9:33 (cf. ‏لَيْسَ, ܠܰܝܺܬ:
(BDB, s.v. “Preface,” paragraph 33.)

These Aramisms are actually more common than you might think when looking through the book of Job.
However, one can look at the apparatus and find this:

33     a nonn Mss  לוּ cf 16,4

So there's a few Medieval Hebrew manuscripts, The Old Greek, and the Syriac that preserve the impossible wish: לוּ.
Here is the text they preserve:

“εἴθε ἦν ὁ μεσίτης ἡμῶν καὶ ἐλέγχων καὶ διακούων ἀνὰ μέσον ἀμφοτέρων·” (Job 9:33 LXX1)
“Utinam esset nobis arbiter, et qui argueret, et qui audiret inter utrosque.” (Job 9:33 V-LATINA)
”ܐܫܬܘܦ ܕܝ݂ܢ ܐܝܬ ܡܟܣܢܐ ܒܝܢܬܢ݁. ܕܢܣܝܡ ܐܝܕܗ ܥܠ ܦܘܡܐ ܕܬܪ̈ܝܢ.“ (Job 9:33 PESHOT-T)

All of the versions (besides Jerome's vulgate) preserve the wish.
The change of the vowel from a waw to an aleph isn't an obstacle, since there is an alternate spelling for the impossible wish:

3863  † לוּ 17 and ‏לוּא († 1 S 14:30, Is 48:18, 63:19), also ‏לֻא (Qr
‏לוּ‎), † 2 S 18:12, 19:7 (Ar. ‏لَوْ‎, Aram. ‏ܠܘܰܝ‎, ‏לְוַי‎, Mishn.
‏לְוַי‎,
(BDB, s.v. “לוּ,” 530.)

From a text-critical point of view, there is a case to be made for either reading.
